# Error occurs with "apt update -y && apt install iptables-persistent"

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am trying to run the command

```
apt update -y && apt install iptables-persistent
```

and always an error returns.

I connected to three different servers one in Greece, one in Austria, one in USA and there is always the same error.

The error says

```
Failed to fetch http://mirror……..
Temporary failure resolving ‘mirror…….
Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with –fix-missing?
```

Should I try an other day?

Comment: Please update the question with full commands and errors.

Comment: Run `apt update -y` and `apt install iptables-persistent` separately. Please [edit] your question, copy&paste the command and the full output/error message to your question and format it as a code block, e.g. by using the `{}` tool of the editor field.

Comment: You could read the whole messages, check to see if the archive mirrors being used have any issues currently reported, or are reported as being *up-to-date*.  We cannot read partial messages, so you'll need to look up that detail yourself.

Comment: I executed the two commands separately but the errors remain.

May I ask. How can I redirect the screen and keyboard and still been able to see the messages on screen and type keys?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for in the last comment; but I gather it's `tee`.  Check out the manual for `tee` to see if it's what you're after (ie. `man tee`).  eg. If you wanted to see the results of `ls` & save a copy in the file `blah`, you'd use `ls | tee blah`